# WebAssembly Instatation

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

I try to create a c code file about opening of text file in my directory and I got this error
**" Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: WebAssembly Instantiation: Imports argument must be present and must be an object
at fetch.then.then.then.module (wa.js:7) "**

This is my JS file.

```
let openFile;

function loadWasm(filename) {
return fetch(filename)
.then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
.then(bits => WebAssembly.compile(bits))
.then(module => { return new WebAssembly.Instance(module) });
}

loadWasm('test.wasm')
.then(instance => {
add = instance.exports._Z8openFilev;
})
```

And this is my create c file

```
`#include <stdio.h>

   int openFile()
   {
      FILE *file = fopen("example.txt", "rb");
         if (!file) {
          printf("cannot open file\n");
          return 1;
    }
     while (!feof(file)) {
        char c = fgetc(file);
        if (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
     }
  }
    fclose (file);
     return 0;
  }`
```

and here's my WAT file.

```
     (module
  (type $FUNCSIG$iii (func (param i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (type $FUNCSIG$ii (func (param i32) (result i32)))
  (import "env" "fclose" (func $fclose (param i32) (result i32)))
  (import "env" "feof" (func $feof (param i32) (result i32)))
  (import "env" "fgetc" (func $fgetc (param i32) (result i32)))
  (import "env" "fopen" (func $fopen (param i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (import "env" "putchar" (func $putchar (param i32) (result i32)))
  (import "env" "puts" (func $puts (param i32) (result i32)))
  (table 0 anyfunc)
  (memory $0 1)
  (data (i32.const 16) "example.txt\00")
  (data (i32.const 32) "rb\00")
  (data (i32.const 48) "cannot open file\00")
  (export "memory" (memory $0))
  (export "_Z8openFilev" (func $_Z8openFilev))
  (func $_Z8openFilev (; 6 ;) (result i32)
  (local $0 i32)
  (local $1 i32)
   (block $label$0
   (br_if $label$0
    (i32.eqz
      (tee_local $0
       (call $fopen
     (i32.const 16)
      (i32.const 32)
   )
  )
 )
)
    (block $label$1
     (br_if $label$1
     (call $feof
      (get_local $0)
     )
    )
    (loop $label$2
     (block $label$3
       (br_if $label$3
       (i32.eq
        (i32.and
         (tee_local $1
          (call $fgetc
           (get_local $0)
          )
         )
         (i32.const 255)
        )
        (i32.const 255)
       )
      )
      (drop
       (call $putchar
        (i32.shr_s
         (i32.shl
           (get_local $1)
           (i32.const 24)
          )
           (i32.const 24)
          )
        )
      )
     )
      (br_if $label$2
       (i32.eqz
        (call $feof
         (get_local $0)
        )
      )
     )
    )
   )
    (drop
     (call $fclose
     (get_local $0)
    )
   )
   (return
    (i32.const 0)
   )
  )
  (drop
   (call $puts
    (i32.const 48)
   )
  )
  (i32.const 1)
 )
)
```

Is there anything wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is something wrong you have:

```
  (import "env" "fclose" (func $fclose (param i32) (result i32)))
  (import "env" "feof" (func $feof (param i32) (result i32)))
  (import "env" "fgetc" (func $fgetc (param i32) (result i32)))
  (import "env" "fopen" (func $fopen (param i32 i32) (result i32)))
  (import "env" "putchar" (func $putchar (param i32) (result i32)))
  (import "env" "puts" (func $puts (param i32) (result i32)))
```

The importObject is the second parameter in Instance
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Instance
these docs say

> There must be one matching property for each declared import of module
>   or else a WebAssembly.LinkError is thrown.

but you choose to omit importObject so none is matched. Don't know why but seems that developer of you browser handles the Error handling different so you get TypeError instead of LinkError.

Comment: I dont really understand what have you said im sorry. But I get some part of what you say. So you mean I have a missing importObject in my code or in my JS file?

Comment: In yours JS file. WebAssembly.Instance(module) should be WebAssembly.Instance(module,importObject)

Comment: Do I need to put one by one all the importObject inline with modules? Or is there's other way for me to open a text file or other file in my directory?

Comment: When using Browser you have to emulate the functions. Maybe someone else did the work already. Also accessing files in local directory maybe not possible because of browser securety restriction

Comment: I see. I think I need to change my c++ code and I will use File System API https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#filesystem-api-filesystems.